# Probability of containing N distinct elements in a multiset?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have a set $S = \lbrace A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L\rbrace$, that I want to create a multiset with.

Suppose I create the multiset $MS$ from *combination with repetition* of 4 from 12 $Cr(N=12, R=4)$ from the set $S$. The members should be like this:

$MS = \lbrace AAAA, AAAB, ..., LLLL\rbrace$ with size $Cr(N=12, R=4) = 1365$

Let say I have a discrete random variable $X = $ the number of distinct element. For example:
$AAAA = 1$, $AABC = 3$, $CDEF = 4$, and $AAKK = 2$.

My question is:

1. How to calculate the probability of *each* $P(X=1), P(X=2), ..., P(X=R)$ ..?

I know $P(X=1)$, which is the proportion of only $\lbrace AAAA, BBBB, ..., LLLL\rbrace$ in the multiset $MS$. Given the example, it would be $\frac{N}{Cr(N=12, R=4)} = \frac{12}{1365} = 0.009$

I also know $P(X=R)$ which is the proportion of distinct combination $\lbrace ABCD, ABCE, ..., IJLK\rbrace$ from the multiset $MS$. I could obtain it with *combination without repetition* like this $\frac{C(N=12, R=4)}{Cr(N=12, R=4)} = \frac{495}{1365} = 0.3626$.

What I don't know is the value in between and the methods to calculate them.

Later if I understand it, I would like to be able to calculate $P(X=1), P(X=2), ..., P(X=r)$ in general way for combination with repetition $Cr(N=n, R=r)$ with large $n$ and $r$ eg. $n>10^6$ and $r>10^3$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thankyou. I've revised the notation..